# How to parse plist data in to UITableView using appropriate keys?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, plist

I am very new to Objective-C. Here is what I want. I have a tab view app for an iPhone. In one of the tabs I need to have table view with a data from the plist file.
Data consist of text, pictures and location.

Comment: How do you store pictures in plist file?

Comment: This is a requirement, not a specific question. Please read the FAQ. What have you tried so far, and which specific part are you having trouble with?

Comment: I have made tab view project, i add table view in one of the view, now i want to populate that table with the content of my plist

Comment: I think of using cellInfo or cellTitle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this  :

```
SString *myFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistName" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];
```

Comment: you should use NSDictionary to store it. Not an Array.

Comment: each item is a bunch of strings

Comment: This is the code to get datas From Plist. you'll add it in the "viewDidLoad" of your TableViewController. Save the NSDictionary.
And you'll use it in : cellforRowAtIndexPath

Comment: My table view controler is in storyboard and i cant see any code just ui everywhere

Comment: come on ... just find a tutorial "how to tableViewController" at first ... you'll know how to link a class inherit of UITableViewController who's delegate with UiTableViewControllerDelegate ... 

just google a good Tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Plist file is in fact a xml file (you can open in in external editor and you should see the structure). So you should store data in NSDictionary (*object* and *keys* structure like xml file!).

For example:

```
    NSString *plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plistFile" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

I don't know if you have in plist file Arrays or Strings... you should provide some more information.